# Multi-module project in Intellij IDEA 13.1.13 with Android+Gradle

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

Is it possible to add a Gradle managed Android **module** to an existing IntelliJ project that already has other modules? Specifically, when adding a new Android module to an existing project I don't get the option to select 'Gradle: Android Application'. However, I do get this option if I select 'New **Project**' instead of 'New **Module**'.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 13.1.13.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply select File->"import module" then select the build.gradle file for the project.  That's how I add multiple Gradle projects to one Intellij project.

Comment: My question was for adding new (not currently existing) modules.

Comment: Have the same problem in 2019. Seems a problem since 2014. I can't believe it.